# IOException - no idea why?

Tags: java

I have the following error:

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: flexitime.UniSystems
```

What is the usual reason for this?
I am trying to read a file in called storage.dat.

The code where it gets the error is

```
private void loadFile() {
    try {
        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream inputObjects = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
        system = (UniSystems)inputObjects.readObject();
        inStream.close();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException err) {
        // Class in the file does not have a matching class definition
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please contact IT Support quoting code CNF",
                "Application error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException err) {
        // Some other IO error has occurred
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please contact IT Support quoting code IIO",
                "Application error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        err.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It makes it through until the 2nd catch and then throws the error back.
Any ideas?

Comment: From the exception it seems like "UniSystems" doesnt implement Serializable. Are you sure that is the object you are reading?

Comment: Where would I need serializable? And the file reads in and then uses UniSystems to do the populating.

Answer (score 1):

> java.io.NotSerializableException: flexitime.UniSystems

It seems that UniSystems is not Serializable.

It needs to be in order for ObjectInputStream to work.

Did the class change since you wrote the file?

Comment: I have definitely made that UniSystems serializable!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the error is there directly. Its a writing error, and that code appears to read.

Your class probably doesn't have a UUID to be serialized.

Otherwise if you have references, you need to mark them as `transient` I believe the keyword is.However, references shouldn't raise an exception, just break when you try to use the object since the reference is (unless you win the lotto) invalid on the remote host.